# How to navigate to cs file that derives from custom ApplicationPage (with xaml)

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

How can I navigate to .cs file that derives from custom PhoneApplicationPage? The inheritance chain looks like this: PhoneApplicationPage -> My casual page with xaml and cs -> page that will derive all with little modifications. `NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/NewPage.cs", UriKind.Relative));` throws exception...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I have a workaround for the problem. As Barry Franklin has said it is impossible to navigate to .cs file, but it is possible to .xaml. The solution is to create a typical PhoneApplication page (xaml and cs), change the base type for our class (our class needs to derive from phone application page) and remove `InitializeComponent();` from the constructor, this should be only in base class. This way the xaml is not loaded and we are using the layout from base class.

Answer (score 0):

You can't navigate to a .cs file, only .xaml files which contain the "views". A .cs file is not actually a page, just the "code behind" that drives the page and holds the logic that implements the functionality of the page.

You can do this:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/NewPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

but not what you have...

Answer (score 0):

As Barry has said, only navigate to the .xaml page.
Though I wonder why you'd need to derive from a phoneaplicationpage, perhaps there's a better way?

Comment: I have two pages with the same layout. Visually they are the same, but they are doing two different things. They have about 15 methods in common, only a few differs. Instead of copy-pasting the code I want to have the common code and xaml in base class and only override the needed methods.